# Datagrid Checkbox in UWP

Tags: checkbox, uwp, datagrid, document

I am struggling to find a working example of a utilised checkbox for my datagrid in UWP. I would like to use my check box -> press a button -> do X.

I dont suppose any of you could either give me an example of the process or point me to a documented example? Thanks

This is what I have:

```
<StackPanel Margin="169,33,0,0" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF383838"/>
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="EmployeeGrid" Margin="170,55,35,35"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind persons}"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Black"
                           SelectedItem="itemSelected" >
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee ID"
                                             Binding="{Binding PersonId}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"
                                             Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"
                                             Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Address"
                                             Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Position"
                                             Binding="{Binding Position}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Pay Rate (ph)"
                                             Binding="{Binding PayratePH}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Sex"
                                             Binding="{Binding Sex}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="TaxCode"
                                             Binding="{Binding TaxCode}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Email"
                                             Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Emergency Contact"
                                             Binding="{Binding EmergencyDetails}"/>
                <controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected"  
                                                    />
                

            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> like to use my check box -> press a button -> do X.

DataGrid contains [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) that used to custom cell, you could insert `CheckBox` into  `CellTemplate` and binding the Checked with data model bool property, when you want to check the `CheckBox`, please modify model's bool property.

```
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Check">
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Id}" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

For more detail please refer this code [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/DataGridTest).

Comment: Hi!! Thank you so much for the response.I attempted to implement this and my grid crashed ha! It wouldn't let me rebuild either. I am most likely just stupid. I havent used the datagridtemplatecoloumn before.  Do you mind if I add my xaml to the question and perhaps point out why im stupid?? hahaha

Comment: Im sure theres more than one reason

Comment: Sure, please go ahead.

Comment: Thank you, its added. The checkbox is the last entry.  Would I add the template column to this?

Comment: Ok, I checked, I will share a demo for you, you could check it clearly.

Comment: @DarrenFinnegan, sample added.